# Is it possible to access the contents of iframe via chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browser, google-chrome-frame

I want to ask is there ANY way or extension that can pre-highlight text within the iframe whenever a new window is opened containing iframe? I have tried many extension but none of them works. 
I need to filter out content based on certain keywords and the content is within iframe. I can do it with CTRL+F but there are many keywords like 10-15 within each article to be found. So it makes my job very tough and time consuming. Few extensions that I have tried from chrome are multi highlighter, pearls, FF but none of them seems to work.

I also know the reason why these extension can't access content within the iframe i.e. due to cross origin policies.

But I also remember around an year ago I worked with chrome extension named 'Autofill' that could pre-select form elements whenever I opened new chrome window containing iframe.

So is there any work around?

Answer (score 2):

You can set your extension permission to run content scripts in all frames as document at http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#registration by setting all_frames to true in the content scripts section of your manifest file. Adding to Google's example from that page, part of your manifest file might look like

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*"],
      "css": ["mystyles.css"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "myscript.js"],
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

You'll need to be careful since your content scripts are going to be inject into the page once for the parent page and one for each iFrame on the page. Once your content script is injected into all frames on the page you can work your magic with finding and highlighting text.

```js
if (window === top) {
  console.log('Running inside the main document', location.href);
} else {
  console.log('Running inside the frame document', location.href,
    [...document.querySelectorAll('*')]);
}
```

Comment: Tried what you suggested. Downloaded .crx file of that extension, changed it to .zip file and then edited manifest.json to include "all_frames": true. And then I zipped that file and changed the file type to .crx. While trying to install that .crx file in the browser I got the error:
Package is invalid: 'CRX_MAGIC_NUMBER_INVALID'.

How to fix that?

Comment: Ok I got around with how to pack the extension. When I try to pack the extension via chrome browser it says: 
Manifest is not a valid JSON file. Syntax error at line,20 colum 4, syntax error. 
Line 20 is the line where I have added "all_frames": true